# Asp.net Core EF options.UseInMemoryDatabase System.TypeLoadException

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I used EF in Asp.net Core, but got below error in below code:

```
public class TodoContext : DbContext
{
    public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }

}
```

Error Message:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Here is my Project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    //Dependence for MVC
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    //Dependence for EF
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
    //Dependence for EF with SQL, this is avalible under VS 2017 RC
    //"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    //Entity Framework commands to maintain the database
    //"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    //used for Razor pages which are compiled at runtime,and the compiler needs access to reference assemblies,
    //to make sure it compiles correctly
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Reards,
Edward

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After trying, I changed "1.0.0-rc2-final" to "1.1.0" which I already have tried, but I found there is an warning, "Dependency conflict. CoreMVCWebAPI 1.0.0 expected Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory >= 1.1.0 but received 1.0.0-rc2-final", after install this package manually instead of only changing project.json, it works now.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
```

Comment: Thanks @edward  it working, but I have already installed the  EntityFrameworkCore it should contain In Memory as well. Isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that I had to restart VS2017 before the package restore was recognised.  Prior to that I was getting an error

> DbContextOptionsBuilder does not contain a definition for
>   UseInMemoryDatabase() ...

I hope this saves you time.