# Having trouble with UseInMemoryDatabase ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I was using this tutorial: [Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) but I get an error in `Startup.cs` after installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` from Nuget.

The error message is:

> Error CS1061  'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseInMemoryDatabase' and no accessible extension method 'UseInMemoryDatabase' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This instruction refers to this point in the project "Register the database context".

Here is the code for startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TodoApi.Models;

namespace TodoApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>
               opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I looked online but couldn't find any fix for this problem, I have to say I installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` version 5.0, and in the tutorial is version 3.0 but I don't think this is the issue.

The error I get occurs here:

```
services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>
               opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
```

Comment: You have to install the InMemory package - noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).  You should also note that `The in-memory database is designed for testing only` per the documentation.

Comment: Install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory`

Comment: @Jonesopolis So what shall I use? Or is it okay to use this one, and make it according to the tutorial?

Comment: @MateiAnghel definitely stick with what is in the tutorial.  I just wanted to make you aware that this package shouldn't be used in any 'real' code

Comment: @Jonesopolis Thank you very much, that solved my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp.net Core EF options.UseInMemoryDatabase System.TypeLoadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528986/asp-net-core-ef-options-useinmemorydatabase-system-typeloadexception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article you used explains that you need to add the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory/) package in the section [Add a Database Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-database-context-1), in the `Add NuGet packages` box :

> Use the preceding instructions to add the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory NuGet package

This package adds the provider *and* the [UseInMemoryDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.inmemorydbcontextoptionsextensions.useinmemorydatabase?view=efcore-5.0) extension method

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the package: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory